# MySQL Transpose (Pivot) Variation: move all combinations of columns into new rows

Tags: mysql, pivot

any idea how to make this happen in MySQL:

Have Data:

```
Item, class, x, y, z, A, B, C
1,     new,  1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
2,     red,  1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1
3,     new,  0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
```

(Data is also be in form `1, new, X, AB` or `2, red, XY, BC` if that is an easier point of departure...)

Need:

```
1, new, X, A
1, new, X, B
2, red, X, B
2, red, X, C
2, red, Y, B
2, red, Y, C
3, new, Z, A
3, new, Z, C
```

Any help would be awesomely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For few "xyzABC..." columns you can use this:

```
SELECT item,class,'x','A' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE x=1 AND a=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'x','B' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE x=1 AND b=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'x','C' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE x=1 AND c=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'y','A' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE y=1 AND a=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'y','B' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE y=1 AND b=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'y','C' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE y=1 AND c=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'z','A' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE z=1 AND a=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'z','B' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE z=1 AND b=1 UNION
SELECT item,class,'z','C' FROM `test_pivot` WHERE z=1 AND c=1
```

Comment: Slick - nice. Fortunately, yes, I'm dealing with exactly a 3 x 3 (xyz ABC) - so no issues. Though even then, it does eat some time/memory generating the 15,000+ entries for my data set (41 seconds on my netbook.)

Comment: Try to add indexes on x,y,z,A,B,C columns.

Comment: Sounds fun - but what does that mean exactly ;)

Comment: [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Right - Gotcha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using nested `case` statements like this:

```
 select t.item, t.class, 
 Case when t.X = 1 then 'X' else
      case when t.Y = 1 then 'Y' else
           case when t.Z = 1 then 'Z' end
      end
 end ,
 Case when t.A = 1 then 'A' else 
      case when t.B = 1 then 'B' else
           case when t.C = 1 then 'C' end
      end
 end
 from YourTableName t
```

Comment: Nice - but unless I'm missing something - this just gives one entry per item, and does not loop through all possible combinations of xyz/ABC.

Comment: No, it will give you all possible combinations becouse it it selects two entities one for `xyz` using the first `case` statement and the other entity for `ABC` from the first `case` statement and each `case` statement from the two check for its possible combination like `if x, if y, if z` the same for the second case, so you get all possible combination, actually i doesn't test it, Have you??

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it - and came up with one new record for each original record. It looks at the combinations, but it does not create a new row for each possible combination. Also, if I am not mistaken, doesn't this use of nested case work the same as a nested if? Thanks for the help - I'm just trying to figure it all out.